# How to safely make Typescript work with a custom backend API

Tags: django, typescript, api, vue.js, svelte

I am making use of API endpoint routes in my application. In these endpoints http requests about the data  are processed by the backend with the help of a PRISMA ORM.

However, i have to use something else for the frontend and started to write typescript types that resemble my backend types. This is very counterintuitive coming from programming languages like haskell or other typed languages.

It seems the endpoint sits in the middle and is a source of all kinds of incompatibilities that might arise in the future. Because now I have 3 points of failure, the endpoint, the API and frontend typescript types (that are not even compiled and available at runtime.)

Is there a more type-safe way to fix the endpoint-in-the-middle-problem?

I've looked at several obscure fullstack projects such as Urweb and the less obscure Django but they lack an expressive templating language such as in Svelte or Vue. Are there other ways to make automatic type safe api endpoint code?

Comment: You could generate TS types from OpenAPI APIs, as the answer says. See https://github.com/prisma/prisma/discussions/5757 . Currently you're on your own with it.

Comment: @EstusFlask i have tried this, but the objects in my frontend are generally incomplete type versions of the ones generated. To flexible work with those i need to omit the id property. At the same time relation properties are also omitted during generation by Prisma.

Comment: Yes, interfaces can be processed to a desirable form with utility types like `Omit`. The absence of relations is the problem that needs to be solved. Considering that OpenAPI is not supported in Prisma, what did you try? Did you auto-generate a client with types? Since the question is general and not limited to Prisma, the answer is OpenAPI (Swagger). Went this way with types for Django API.

Comment: Okay, so i will write an OpenAPI spec. Yes the relations are difficult. For the moment, I do not have a solution at all @EstusFlask. I am just juggling with the types and the prisma definitions but it's not clean. I wonder if there is another way.

Comment: I don't currently use Prism myself. Probably generator template https://www.prisma.io/docs/concepts/components/prisma-client/working-with-prismaclient/generating-prisma-client could be customized to output types that you need

Answer (score 2):

It seems like a problem of single source of truth. There are multiple ways to solve such problems.

For example: You could generate types from schema (eg from Swagger or Prisma itself). Or even generate schemas from types like Typeorm.

There are tools like `swagger-typescript-api` and `swagger-typescript-codegen` and others that can generate code for doing requests and parsing them

Comment: So you would suggest switching to OpenAPI and stay with Prisma? In the comment is was mentioned that both at the same time are not supported. Maybe a full switch to typeorm then?

Answer (score 0):

I've solved the problem not by generating types in the frontend, but by

1. simplifying the Prisma schema file, so I don't need complicated types
2. making helper functions on the backend circumvent long database queries
3. writing Svelte route endpoints that function as gateways between the frontend and the backend, calling backend helper functions
4. writing simple helper functions in the frontend that only use the scalar type information provided by the type definitions in @prisma/client.

The biggest remaining difficulty is keeping frontend, endpoints and backend independent and maintainable.

Answer (score 0):

*Note: I’m one of the authors of Remult*

You can use [Remult](https://github.com/remult/remult) to create type-safe API endpoints from your TypeScript model classes without any code generation. It also has an API client you can use directly from frontend code to query and manipulate data without any helper functions.